# How to display image from database path

Tags: php, image

I have an MVC pattern and I am trying to display image from database path.
Here is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h1 ><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $results['task']->username )?></h1>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $results['task']->email )?></p>
    <p><?php echo $results['task']->text?></p>
    <img src="<?php echo $results['task']->imagePath?>" />

    <p>Published on <?php echo date('j F Y', $results['task']->publicationDate)?></p>

    <p><a href=".?action=home">Return to Homepage</a></p>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
<?php

require( "config/config.php" );
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

switch ( $action ) {
  case 'viewTask':
    viewTask();
    break;
}

function viewTask() {
  if ( !isset($_GET["taskId"]) || !$_GET["taskId"] ) {
    homepage();
    return;
  }

  $results = array();
  $results['task'] = Task::getById( (int)$_GET["taskId"] );
  $results['pageTitle'] = $results['task']->username . " ";
  require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/viewTask.php" );
}
```

And getById function inside Task class:

```
class Task
{
  // Свойства
  public $id = null;

  public $username = null;
  public $email = null;

  public $text = null;
  public $publicationDate = null;

  public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = $data['username'];
    if ( isset( $data['email'] ) ) $this->email = $data['email'];
    if ( isset( $data['text'] ) ) $this->text = $data['text'];
    if ( isset( $data['publicationDate'] ) ) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
    if ( isset( $data['status'] ) ) $this->status = (int) $data['status'];
  }

  public static function getById( $id ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM tasks WHERE id = :id";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    if ( $row ) return new Task( $row );
  }
}
```

How can I get an image and display it on the page? Thanks

Comment: what error / op you are getting?

Comment: are you trying to do this in the getById function?

Comment: And what's your question?  What isn't working?

Comment: @David I am getting empty image instead of required image

Comment: @webpic getting empty image instead of required image

Comment: @Akin yes in getById function

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy it means you are  getting blank result try to `print_r($result)` check if has value in it.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy: What's the actual HTML rendered for the `<img>` element?  What should be originally *setting* the value for `$results['task']->imagePath`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function inside the Task class:

```
public function getImage($id){ 
   $path = "SELECT imgPath FROM tasks WHERE id = :id";
   return $path;
}
```

Also add it to your HTML:

```
<img src="<?php echo $results['task']->getImage($results['task']->id); ?>" />
```

Have you tried anything? Post it

Comment: Still getting empty image

Comment: In your constructor you don't have any image. Are you sure you have it in the DB ?

Comment: Try declaring an attribute public $imagePath = null and then setting this attribute in the contructor with some value. After that you can just take it by $results['task']->imagePath

Comment: Omg I forgot to add it inside constructor. it works now. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

you have miss something like try with this

```
<img src="<?php echo $results['task']->imagePath; ?>" />
```